# Why do I get the error 'HTTP Response: 403 Forbidden' when I try to call the amazon api in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I'm creating a Ruby on Rails application and am following the instructions step for step based on the gem required to call the amazon API (https://github.com/jugend/amazon-ecs) when searching for an item.

This is my code in the Ruby app:

```
Amazon::Ecs.options = {
  :associate_tag => '[*****]',
  :AWS_access_key_id => '[*****]',       
  :AWS_secret_key => '[*****]'
}


res = Amazon::Ecs.item_search('soccer books')
puts res.total_items
```

I've tried regenerating my keys, still doesn't work and am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible issue in gem as they already solved if for 1.9 . You can check changelog here https://github.com/jugend/amazon-ecs/blob/master/CHANGELOG . This confirm that issue resolved for 1.9 . But might be come up again due to new changes they done. So my opinion is to create an issue in gem as well.

Comment: How can I find out why this is happening though? Is there a way to be certain whether it's the gem or something on my end?

Answer (score 0):

please check s3-bucket timestamp and you local machine timestamp. If its greate the 10hr or more s3 considers as invalid request and refuse it.

Comment: what is s3-bucket timestamp?